# "Callback was already called" during truffle test using a solidity testfile

Tags: solidity, truffle-test

I'm creating a contract/token which extends the openzeppelin ERC20.sol and Ownable.sol.

My contract has no own logic yet and looks like this:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.2;

import "../node_modules/openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
import "../node_modules/openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/ownership/Ownable.sol";

contract OwnToken is Ownable, ERC20 {

    constructor() public {
    }
}
```

Compiling works as expected but when I try to run `truffle test` it fails and gives me:

```
Error: Callback was already called.
    at C:\Users\towo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\truffle-core\~\async\dist\async.js:966:1
    at C:\Users\towo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\truffle-core\~\async\dist\async.js:3885:1
```

The test I have is only a dummy and looks like this:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.2;

import "truffle/Assert.sol";
import "../contracts/MoniToken.sol";
import "truffle/DeployedAddresses.sol";

contract TestOwnToken {

    function testDummy() public {
        OwnToken ownToken = new OwnToken();
        address expected = 0x1C8994b9A1802374579AF9d2312a6C2eF26A24F5;
        Assert.equal(ownToken.owner(), expected, "Error");
    }
}
```

When I exclude the solidity test and include an Javascript-test, everything works as expected which means, `truffle test` is running fine. The Javascript test does the same as the solidity version.

Regarding the error and the fact that a Javascript-test is running fine it seems this has something to do with async/await within the truffle-suite itself. Does anyone has any idea on this? Maybe I'm missing something? It looks like an truffle issue at the first glance.

**EDIT:**
Deleted the code for the Javascript test since it is not relevant to the question as stated by @goodvibration

Comment: `contract TestOwnToken` looks irrelevant to your question, so you may want to remove that code snippet altogether.

Comment: You deleted the wrong piece of code!!!

Comment: Why? The Javascript-test is running and isn't necessary for my problem because it's related to the solidity-test.

Comment: The error occurs when you run your Truffle test, which no longer appears in your question. This Truffle test makes no use of `contract TestOwnToken`, which is therefore redundant in your question.

Comment: I have met the same problem

Comment: @goodvibration That contract you're complaining about is the Solidity implementation of a test. You don't have to write tests just in JavaScript, and here the `truffle test` command runs that contract as a test.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and I managed it as follows:
https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/issues/2176

So just by manually deleting the build folder and creating it back again just running the test.